# Missing "show package contents" cmd

Tags: finder, macos, package-management

I was trying to extract the contents of a `.pkg` file, and right clicking on it should usually allow the context sensitive `Show Package Contents` option.  However, it does not seem to show on any .pkg file I can find on my system.

I have since expanded the contents on the command line using this command:

```
StuffeMac:Desktop stuffe$ pkgutil --expand AirPortUtility56.pkg ./dan2/
```

Which worked fine, and inside this package was another `.pkg` file.  Right clicking on this and `Show Package Contents` is back again, but only for the one I just expanded...

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Show Package Contents* is not for showing the contents of .pkg files, it's for showing the hidden structure for Applications (and other bundles), which are actually folders. You can use the program [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) to look at the contents of .pkg files.

To answer the question in your comment, here's how you can tell in Terminal. When you perform an `ls -l` command, directories have *d* as the first character in the line.

```
516 $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    3 steve  admin         102 Jan  6  2011 Form Viewer.app
drwxrwxrwx@   3 root   admin         102 Jan 18  2010 FormViewerFonts.pkg
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff  2157020198 Jun 30  2012 MacTeX-2012.pkg
```

In this example, the first two entries are bundles and the last isn't.

Comment: Is there some way of telling if a file ending in `.pkg` is actually a bundle or something else?  In this instance both the original file and the contents of that file were `.pkg` files

Comment: If it's a bundle, *Show Package Contents* will show up in the context menu. If not, it won't. You can also look at it in Terminal. A bundle's structure isn't hidden there. If it's a bundle it shows up as a directory.

Comment: I added a Terminal example to my answer.

Comment: Any idea what makes a directory show as a package as opposed to as a regular directory?

Comment: @DanRosenstark Nope. You should post that as a question so we can both find out.

Comment: Not my best question-asking, but anyway: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280280/what-makes-an-osx-package-show-as-a-package

Answer (score -1):

Quick and Easy:

- "Duplicate" package file.
- Righ-Click and Run "Show package contents" on the duplicate file

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on *how* to duplicate the file and *how* to "Show package contents" as many users may not know how to do these things. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.